Fraction of methylated sites in restriction-modification systems
Given a strain that is expressing proteins of a restriction-modification system (like EcoRI), is there data to measure the fraction of metylated target sites? I am just looking for an approximation, so in vitro assays also should work.
For EcoRI, I have seen people measuring kinetic constants for the methyltranferase and couting number of molecules in a cell. But from that I do not think I am able to predict the fraction of modified sites, only the fraction of enzyme bound to DNA at a time.

I find it difficult to understand your question. When you refer to target sites, which DNA are you referring to — E.coli DNA or invading bacteriophage DNA? And why would you expect not all EcoRI sites in Ecoli to be methylated, if that is what you mean? Or in a phage infection, that would be related to the number of progeny phage. Or are you thinking of restriction enzymes in cloning? If so the problem is one of enzyme kinetics.

By target sites I mean the sites recognized by the Methyltransferase in the own bacteria DNA. I would expect almost all of them to be methylated, but probably a small percentage may remain unmethylated due to loss of the methyl group, or DNA replication before division. I expect this percentage to be small, but I have not been able to find any data about that.

Ok. That’s a fair question (to which I don’t have an answer). Perhaps you could edit the question to make that clear, or I will do it for you if you wish.
